# TCPDF Memory Issue Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, memory-limit

I am using TCPDF for downloading PDF. For smaller records, it is working fine.But for large data ie 1000 records, it is showing the following error,

```
Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded
Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)
```

I have set memory limit and max execution time in php using ini_set But it not works.I also tried changing the value of memory_limit in php.ini from 128M to 512M.This also not working.

My file is

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Customer Receipts Report</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

        <style>
             @font-face {
            font-family: SourceSansPro;
  src: url(../../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf);
/*  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url(../fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf);*/
}
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
   font-family:"Armata", sans-serif;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

table th {
  white-space: nowrap;        
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #4A7171;
  color:white;
  font-size:12px;
}
            html,body{
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .login{color:#fff}
            .table-responsive table td
            {
                font-weight: 400;
                font-size: 12px;
                color:#222;
                text-align:center !important;
            } 
            .form-control {
                border:1px solid #eee;
            }
            .input-sm
            {
                border-radius: 3px;
            }
            input.input-sm
            {
                margin-left: 10px
            }
            #dataTables-example_info,#dataTables-example_length label
            {
                color:#666;
            }
            #dataTables-example_wrapper {
  width: 86.5% !important;
}
            label{
                text-transform: lowercase;
            }
            .black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        }

        .white_content {
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                top: 7%;
                left: 20%;
                padding: 16px;
                border: 2px solid #7B8D8C;
                background-color: white;
                z-index:1002;
                overflow: auto;
                height:auto;                                
                width: 30cm;  
                height: 35cm;   
                overflow-y: scroll;
                max-height: 700px;
        }
        #wrapper {width:auto ;margin-bottom:5px;}
        #left{
        float:left;
        width:45%;
        /*background:#7B8D8C*/

        }
        #right{
        /*background:#7B8D8C;*/
        float:right;
        width:45%;
        height:50%;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                           <table style='width:100%;' border=0>
<tr>
<td style='vertical-align:top;text-align:left;background-color:black;'><img src="../../images/logo.png" style="width:140px;margin-left: 20px"/></td>
<td colspan=2 style='background-color:black;color:white;font-size:9px;'> <div style='text-align:right;'>
        <div>Company</div>
        <div>Address</div>
        <div>Address</div>
        <div style='color:white !important;'><a href="mailto:info@gmail.com" style='text-decoration:none;'>info@gmail.com </a></div>
      </div>
</td></tr>
    </table>


                                 <div class="table-responsive">
                                         <br>

                                          <h3 class="page-header" style="text-align:center;"><i class="fa fa-road fa-fw" style="padding-right:10px;"></i> Receipts Report </h3>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" style='width:100% !important;'>
                                    <thead> 
                                        <tr style="background-color:black;color:white;">
                                          <th><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Customer Name</th>
                                            <th><b>#</b> Invoice Number</th>
                                            <th><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Invoice Date</th> 
                                             <th ><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Due date</th> 

                                             <th><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> Payment Status</th> 
                                            <th><i class="fa fa-dollar" style="min-width:10px"></i> Amount</th>                         

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php
                                        $total=0;
                                        for($i=0;$i<count($obj['ar_info']);$i++){

                                            echo "<tr><td>".$obj['ar_info'][$i]['customer_name']."</td><td>".$obj['ar_info'][$i]['invoice_number']."</td><td>".$obj['ar_info'][$i]['invoice_date']."</td><td>".$obj['ar_info'][$i]['due_date']."</td><td>".$obj['ar_info'][$i]['payment_status']."</td><td>".$obj['ar_info'][$i]['invoice_amt']."</td></tr>";

                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>
                            <!-- /.table-responsive -->  

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.panel-body -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>   


    </body>
</html>




   $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
//$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
//$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 049');
//$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
//$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 049', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10);

$pdf->AddPage();
//$html = '<h1>Test TCPDF Methods in HTML</h1>
//<h2 style="color:red;">IMPORTANT:</h2>
//<span style="color:red;">If you are using user-generated content, the tcpdf tag can be unsafe.<br />
//You can disable this tag by setting to false the <b>K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML</b> constant on TCPDF configuration file.</span>
//<h2>write1DBarcode method in HTML</h2>';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);

$pdf->lastPage();
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output('example_049.pdf', 'I');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.pdf"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('customer-receipts-report.pdf'));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
readfile('customer-receipts-report.pdf');
ob_end_flush();
```

Please anyone help me on this issue.

Comment: I think there is some issue with for loop or may be lots of records.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this line in the your code

`set_time_limit(0);`

and this

`ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');`// its not the proper solution but it will do the trick.

Or

`ini_set('memory_limit', '640M');` //Set Proper memory limit in your php file

Comment: I have tried this.Still I am getting blank page and the first error not appears.Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1961 bytes) error is shown.

Comment: Thanks.It is working now by setting ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');But it takes some time.Will it be reduced.

Comment: without looking at your code, no,  and for 1000 records it should take time or may be there will be some issue with while loop. if the answer resolve your issue, please mark it correct.

Comment: the code of TCPDF export php file. the file which doing the export job.